# Gitlab CI/CD can't download private composer package

Tags: laravel, docker, ssh, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to download a private gitlab repository package inside my gitlab project, using the gitlab CI/CD inside a Docker container.

Now I got the following error:

```sh
- Installing {package} (dev-master 30bb2f3): Downloading    Failed to download {package} from dist: Could not authenticate against gitlab.com
80     Now trying to download from source
81   - Installing {package} (dev-master 30bb2f3): Cloning 30bb2f3bb7
82                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
83   [RuntimeException]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
84   Failed to execute git clone --no-checkout 'git@gitlab.com:{user}/{project}/{repo}.git'
```

I tried everything, but the solution..
This post didn't help me: [GitLab CI: "Permission denied" when pulling private composer package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44444727/gitlab-ci-permission-denied-when-pulling-private-composer-package)

#### Info

- I setup SSH correctly, because the deployment of the project will succeed
- I use deploy tokens in my repo url, but it didn't helped
- The private key is set as gitlab variable

My `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
.init_ssh: &init_ssh |
  which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )
  eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
  mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  chmod 700 ~/.ssh
  ssh-keyscan gitlab.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config

Composer:
  stage: Build
  script:
    - *init_ssh
    - composer install --prefer-dist --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-progress --no-scripts
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38570269/6385459
It was the part **Adding the public SSH key as a deploy key to all your private dependencies**. I had a wrong public_key which caused the problem..